# Mixing Constructor set fields and Field Initializers

Tags: c#, oop

When designing a class, are there any guidelines regarding initializing class fields?  There are two separate methods of initialization. I can use either inline field initializers, or I can initialize them in the constructors.  It becomes even more... interesting, when static fields are introduced as then the fields can be initalized when defined, in the static constructor, or in the instance constructor with a check to see if the field has been set already.  This becomes even more confusing when factories are introduced.

**Example 1 - Inline Initilization**

```
    public class ExampleOne
    {
        private readonly IDictionary _collection = new Dictionary();

        ...
    }
```

**Example 2 - Constructor Initialization**

```
    public class ExampleTwo
    {
        private readonly IDictionary _collection;

        public ExampleTwo() 
        {
            _collection = new Dictionary();
        }
        ...
    }
```

**Example 3 - Static Inline Initialization**

```
    public class ExampleThree
    {
        private static readonly IDictionary __collection = new Dictionary();

        ...
    }
```

**Example 4 - Static Constructor Initialization**

```
    public class ExampleFour
    {
        private static IDictionary __collection;

        static ExampleFour() 
        {
            _collection = new Dictionary();
        }

        ...
    }
```

**Example 5 - Static/Instance Constructor Mix Initialization**

```
    public class ExampleFive
    {
        private static readonly IDictionary __collection;
        private static IDictionary __anotherCollection;

        static ExampleFive() 
        {
            _collection = new Dictionary();
        }

        public ExampleFive()
        {
           if( __anotherCollection == null ) 
           {
            __anotherCollection = new Dictionary();
           }
        }

        ...
    }
```

**Example 6 - Factory Methods**

```
    public class ExampleSix
    {
        private static readonly IDictionary __collection;
        private static IDictionary __anotherCollection;

        static ExampleSix() 
        {
            _collection = new Dictionary();
        }

        public static ExampleSix Create()
        {
           if( __anotherCollection == null ) 
           {
            __anotherCollection = new Dictionary();
           }

           var example = new ExampleSix();
           return example;
        }

        ...
    }
```

Currently the classes that I have tend to mix all of these. Although I have tried to avoid setting static fields in the instance constructors.

**Example 7 - Mixed**

```
    public class ExampleSeven
    {
        private static readonly IDictionary __collection = new Dictionary();
        private static readonly IDictionary __anotherCollection;
        private static readonly IDictionary __thirdCollection;
        private static IDictionary __fourthCollection;

        static ExampleSeven() 
        {
            __anotherCollection = new Dictionary();
        }

        public ExampleSeven() 
        {
            if( __thirdCollection == null )
            {
               __thirdCollection = new Dictionary();
            }
        }

        public static ExampleSeven Create()
        {
           if( __fourthCollection == null ) 
           {
            __fourthCollection = new Dictionary();
           }

           var example = new ExampleSeven();
           return example;
        }

        ...
    }
```

I am more concerned, as can be seen in the examples, with fields that are class objects instead of simple primitives. I understand that initializing the fields when they are declared will mark the class as `beforeinit`, and the fact that I cannot pass `this` into fields that are initialized when declared. My concern is primarily in cases similar to above seven examples.  Am I setting myself up for any kind of unforeseen issues by mixing them this way?

Comment: It's really hard to understand what the question is here. *Is* there a question?

Comment: Does sound like a world of hurt you're setting yourself up for. Especially if you plan on subclassing the order of initialization can be counter-intuitive at first glance sometimes. (the static dictionary initialization in the instance constructor looks fun) I strongly suggest you read Eric Lippert's recent [blog series](http://ericlippert.com/2013/02/06/static-constructors-part-one/) on the topic. I would fathom that there's likely a far simpler way of tackling what you're doing with a bit of structure redesign.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair the end of part three was disturbing as Eric got it wrong and Jon Skeet had to correct him on when static field initializers where run.

Comment: @ConradFrix: I can't keep track of *everything* you know. Fortunately Jon can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually it doesn't really matter whether you initialize fields in the constructor or using field initializers. However, there are a few subtleties that you should be aware of regarding the timing and order of operations:

- Instance field initializers and instance constructors run in the following order, which may be surprising:

  - derived class field initializers
  - base class field initializers
  - base class constructor
  - derived class constructor

See this article by Eric Lippert for a discussion on the reasons of this behavior: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/02/18/why-do-initializers-run-in-the-opposite-order-as-constructors-part-two.aspx

- The presence of a static constructor in a class introduces subtle changes in the way the type is initialized. I won't go into the details here, but Jon Skeet has a very thorough article about it: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Beforefieldinit.aspx

To answer your question, there is no definite rule about where you should initialize the fields. Sometimes it is more natural to initialize the field "inline" if the initialization is short, but if it's long it should probably be in the constructor. Sometimes fields *have* to be initialized in the constructor, because field initializers can't contain a reference to `this`. I often have a mix of both styles in my code, and so far I didn't run into issues because of this. Just keep in mind the order of execution mentioned above...

Answer (score 0):

There is not just one answer to this question. Rather, it depends on what sort of thing you want to store in the field and what you want to do with it.

Firstly, ask yourself: is the object in this field absolutely required by ExampleX? Do absolutely ALL use cases for ExampleX involve that field? If not, then it shouldn't be created in the constructor. If it's just used in one method, it should be created in (or passed in to) that method. If it's used in two of more methods, then these should probably be in their own class, i.e. split up the class into two, one which has a dependency on the object in that field and one which does not.

Secondly, do you really need a NEW Dictionary every time you create an ExampleX? Let's change the example - instead of the dictionary it's some kind of service-providing object, expensive to set up but then easy to re-use. In that case you should DEFINITELY pass it in rather than creating it - if you create a new one you are wasting resources, as well as making your program more complicated and less readable, because you introduce hidden dependencies. By passing in the object, you advertise the dependency in the constructor signature (or method signature if you are passing it into a method). Not to mention making it untestable or difficult to test (in the sense of unit test). See http://misko.hevery.com/2008/09/30/to-new-or-not-to-new/

So, to sum up - Do you ALWAYS need it? That tells you whether to create/pass in the object in the constructor or elsewhere. And does it have to be a NEW one? That will tell you whether to create it or pass it in.

Passing in stuff also makes your code WAY more flexible. See http://www.kevinwilliampang.com/2009/11/07/dependency-injection-for-dummies/